# Set History Tracking missing from SFDX code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I went to put my newly create sfdx application onto a different scratch org.  It seems as if the configuration of the 'set history tracking' is not saved when you pull.  I verified if I changed the setting and the pulled nothing will get pulled down. Is there a way to get this into this configuration in the sfdx project?

Comment: @Patlatus Doesn't the answer by Greg Cook on this version of the question provide a stronger solution?

Comment: @DavidReed I find both answers similar and equivalent, both of them can be reduced to a single statement: either remove history tracking from xml files before pushing or do it manually or deploy it later. So they seem to be equivalent to me

Comment: @DavidReed Also neither of these answers is relevant anymore, since now this is not reproducible when using the latest CLI version

Answer (score 4):

I was able to overcome this issue by using the metadata api features of the SFDX command line.  Here is my example use case:

- Account History Tracking needs to be enabled
- Create your scratch org
- Before pushing your repo into the new scratch org,
  run a pre-processor metadata api process.  First, retrieve the metadata.

> sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./scratch-mdapi-datamodel -k ./scratch-mdapi-datamodel/package.xml

scratch-mdapi-datamodel/package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

- Edit the object.xml file for which you need to enable history tracking.  You can remove all of the unnecessary XML.  Here is my example file for the Account.object file:

scratch-mdapi-datamodel/unpackaged/objects/Account.object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
</CustomObject>
```

- Deploy the contents of the object file back to the scratch org using the metadata deploy command:

> sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d scratch-mdapi-preload/unpackaged/ -w 30

- The scratch org now has history tracking enabled for the Account and will accept your repository references for Account fields with history tracking enabled.
- I actually put the contents of my /unpackaged/objects/Account.object into my repo and have scripted this process so that it automatically activates the feature and pushes the repo.  Theoretically any other non-supported DX features could also be provisioned this way until they are officially supported by SFDX.

Answer (score 3):

I have ran into this issue as well. It doesn't matter what  is set to at the object level. It will not push that to a new ScratchOrg. If you have any fields with  set to true you'll get an error that history tracking is not enabled at the object =.

I have had to remove the trackHistory from the field level in the hopes that when I do a metadata api push that it'll leave the value alone in the target environment.

I contacted SF support and got them to create this issue for me if you'd like to vote:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BX2QAM

Thanks!